# Xcode Error for iOS app: [UI Application Delegate] must be called from main thread only

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
inline UnityAppController*  GetAppController()
{
    return (UnityAppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

The lines above give me the error:

> [UI Application Delegate] must be called from main thread only

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: call the finction in mainthread dispatchque()

Comment: While that is true, it doesn't seem to be very helpful for OP, given OP seems to be a beginner. @VineeshTP

Comment: @Nonymous did you get answers of this. still im facing same issues

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the main thread:

Swift:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

  let appController = GetAppController()

}
```

Objective-C:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  UnityAppController* appController = GetAppController();
});
```

Comment: The question is in Objective-C. Please post answers in the correct language.

Comment: @KostiaZzz The DispatchQueue is outside the func no inside, so yes you can return your value inside the async block and using it inside the block (that it's the case of the question) If you need return a value outside just use a completion block